# Android Database "no such column"

Tags: android, database

Hello i'm trying to update a table in my database but i get the error that my column does not exists .
The table is successfuly created before . I am able to fetch information and manipulate them but i cannot update in my edit acticity
Here is my code in parts  :

```
//job_cost table------------------------------------------------
    public static final String KEY_JOBCOSTID = "jobcostID";
    public static final String KEY_JOBCOSTHOURSTREMA = "jobcostHourStrema";
    public static final String KEY_JOBCOSTGROUNDTYPE = "jobcostGroundType";
    public static final String KEY_JOBCOSTPETROL = "jobcostPetrol";
    public static final String KEY_JOBCOSTOIL = "jobcostOil";
    public static final String KEY_JOBCOSTMAINTENANCE = "jobcostMaintenance";
    public static final String KEY_JOBCOSTOTHEREXPENSES = "jobcostOtherExpenses";
    public static final String KEY_JOBCOSTFINAL = "jobcostFinal";

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_JOBCOSTTABLE + "("
                    + KEY_JOBCOSTID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement , "
                    + KEY_JOBCOSTHOURSTREMA + " DOUBLE , "
                    + KEY_JOBCOSTGROUNDTYPE + " TEXT , "
                    + KEY_JOBCOSTPETROL + " DOUBLE , "
                    + KEY_JOBCOSTOIL + " DOUBLE , "
                    + KEY_JOBCOSTMAINTENANCE + " DOUBLE , "
                    + KEY_JOBCOSTFINAL + " DOUBLE , "
                    + KEY_JOBCOSTOTHEREXPENSES + " DOUBLE  )");
        }

public boolean updateJobCost(Cost costTemp,String jobForEdit){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put( "KEY_JOBCOSTHOURSTREMA" , costTemp.getHourStrema());
        cv.put( "KEY_JOBCOSTGROUNDTYPE" , costTemp.getGroundType());
        cv.put( "KEY_JOBCOSTPETROL" , costTemp.getPetrol());
        cv.put( "KEY_JOBCOSTOIL" , costTemp.getOil());
        cv.put( "KEY_JOBCOSTMAINTENANCE" , costTemp.getMaintenance());
        cv.put( "KEY_JOBCOSTOTHEREXPENSES" , costTemp.getOtherExpenses());
        cv.put( "KEY_JOBCOSTFINAL" , costTemp.getCost());
        //cv.put(key, value)
        ourDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(DATABASE_JOBCOSTTABLE, cv, KEY_JOBCOSTID + "=" + jobForEdit, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: show your Log cat output.. and that error mean you are calling written wrong COLUMN_NAME...

Comment: What exactly are the errors that you are getting. Please post your log cat.

Comment: Why are you using double qoutes("") for you key String While these are the Constant String.

Answer (score 2):

In your content values, the key name constants should not be quoted. For example, change

```
 cv.put( "KEY_JOBCOSTHOURSTREMA" , costTemp.getHourStrema());
```

to

```
 cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTHOURSTREMA, costTemp.getHourStrema());
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to remove the quotes in the names of the update:

I mean,

`cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTHOURSTREMA , costTemp.getHourStrema());`

instead of

`cv.put( "KEY_JOBCOSTHOURSTREMA" , costTemp.getHourStrema());`

Answer (score 1):

You're using the key values instead of column names. Change the code to:

```
public boolean updateJobCost(Cost costTemp,String jobForEdit){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTHOURSTREMA , costTemp.getHourStrema());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTGROUNDTYPE , costTemp.getGroundType());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTPETROL , costTemp.getPetrol());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTOIL , costTemp.getOil());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTMAINTENANCE , costTemp.getMaintenance());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTOTHEREXPENSES , costTemp.getOtherExpenses());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTFINAL , costTemp.getCost());
    //cv.put(key, value)
    ourDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(DATABASE_JOBCOSTTABLE, cv, KEY_JOBCOSTID + "=" + jobForEdit, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:- remove double qoutes ("")

```
 cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTHOURSTREMA , costTemp.getHourStrema());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTGROUNDTYPE , costTemp.getGroundType());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTPETROL , costTemp.getPetrol());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTOIL , costTemp.getOil());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTMAINTENANCE , costTemp.getMaintenance());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTOTHEREXPENSES , costTemp.getOtherExpenses());
    cv.put( KEY_JOBCOSTFINAL , costTemp.getCost());
```